# Typescript include JSON file as string in ts file

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, include, require

I have few json-config files in my project. And I want to include it to ts-scripts.

i don't want load files on run or something. I just need get my json-file content in my ts-files as if it where in the files (**after compile** to js-file)

say..

```
var jsonFile = include("path_to_file.json"); //in file: {"x":1}
```

compile to

```
var jsonFile = {"x":1};
```

Is there any possibility for that (without any "script loading")?

Comment: Typescript is good at type checking and that's what it should be used for. You can require json files as you would in normal js, but the advanced use case you are requesting does not seem to have anything to do with typescript. I think Babel is more appropriate for this kind of compilation magic  

Comment: Thanks for Babel.

Comment: Is there some way to squeeze into the compilation process of Typescript? Or i need to use only postprocess parsers?